# Lambda Expressions for Comparing/sorting limited values in fixed, non-natural order

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, compare

I'm trying to sort using Lambda expressions but the problem is that I can't sort in the normal order (ex. 1,2,3,4). I need to sort in another order (ex. 2,1,3,4).
Is there a way to use Lambda expressions to do this?
Here is the code that I want to convert to a Lambda expression (if possible):

```
private static Comparator<Card> bySuit = new Comparator<Card>() {
    public int compare(Card c1, Card c2) {
        int this_suit = c1.getSuit().value();
        int other_suit = c2.getSuit().value();

        if((this_suit == 2 && other_suit == 1) || (this_suit == 1 && other_suit == 2)){
            return other_suit - this_suit;
        }
        return this_suit - other_suit;
    }
};
```

**EDIT**
Found that I could use:

```
private static Comparator<Card> bySuit = (c1, c2) -> {
        int this_suit = c1.getSuit().value();
        int other_suit = c2.getSuit().value();

        if((this_suit == 2 && other_suit == 1) || (this_suit == 1 && other_suit == 2)){
            return other_suit - this_suit;
        }
        return this_suit - other_suit;
};
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: So, you want to have natural order except for first two elements, or only for elements with some specific values? For instance, what should be result or sorting `3,4,5,6`?

Comment: @pshemo only some elements with specific values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't tied to lambda expressions: If you have a limited number of items which you want to sort/compare in a fixed order, you can write that order in an array, then compare the values in the array:

```
int[] myOrder = {2, 1, 3, 4};
Comparator<Card> bySuit = (c1, c2) -> Integer.compare(
    myOrder[c1.getSuit().value() - 1], myOrder[c2.getSuit().value() - 1]);
```

If the values you want to sort aren't a (nearly) unbroken range, you can use a `Map<Key, Integer>`.